# Turn a list of items into multiple dictionaries where each key has only one value from the list

Tags: python

I have a results list that looks like this: [player, club, nationality, country, latitude, longitude]

```
results = [('Edouard Mendy', 'Chelsea FC', 'Senegal', 'Senegal', 14.0, -14.0),
 ('Kepa', 'Chelsea FC', 'Spain', 'Spain', 40.0, -4.0),
 ('Kurt Zouma', 'Chelsea FC', 'France', 'France', 46.0, 2.0),
 ('Andreas Christensen', 'Chelsea FC', 'Denmark', 'Denmark', 56.0, 10.0),
 ('Antonio Rüdiger', 'Chelsea FC', 'Germany', 'Germany', 51.0, 9.0),
 ('Thiago Silva', 'Chelsea FC', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', -10.0, -55.0)]
```

and I want to change it into a dictionary formatted as:

```
players = [{
   {"player": Edouard Mendy,
    "club:": Chelsea FC,
    "nationality": Senegal,
    "country:" Senegal,
    "latitude": 14.0,
    "longitude": -14.0
   }
   {"player": Kepa,
    "club:": Chelsea FC,
    "nationality": Spain,
    "country:" Spain,
    "latitude": 40.0,
    "longitude": -4.0
   }
   etc...  for each player
}]
```

I have tried

```
player = [result[0] for result in results]
club = [result[1] for result in results]
nationality = [result[2] for result in results]
country = [result[3] for result in results]
latitude = [result[4] for result in results]
longitude = [result[5] for result in results]
```

and placed it into a dictionary like so

```
players = {
   "player": player,
   "club": club,
   "nationality": nationality,
   "country": country,
   "latitude": latitude,
   "longitude": longitude
}
```

This result puts all of the results into one dictionary. How can I separate them?

Answer (score 6):

`zip` the dictionary keys with each individual result to create a list of `(key, value)` pairs that you can then convert into a dictionary:

```
keys = ["player", "club", "nationality", "country", "latitude", "longitude"]
players = [dict(zip(keys, result)) for result in results]
print(players)
```

This solution is easily scalable if you have more keys - just add them to the the `keys` list.

Answer (score 2):

```
players = [
{
   "player": result[0],
   "club": result[1],
   "nationality": result[2],
   "country": result[3],
   "latitude": result[4],
   "longitude": result[5]
} for result in results]
```